# Is login a use-case for a user of a system?

Tags: uml, diagrams

I've been researching since my last project last semester and I haven't found a definitive answer for this question. Now I've got one more project to draw a Use-Case diagram and I'm still confused about it.

*In the end, can I create a Login Use-Case or not?*

Because in my project the user must be logged in to access his informations.

I know I can be repeating this question, but no one and nowhere has a consistent answer ☹

Here is an example how I have it in mind:

[image: Login Use Case Example]

If anybody can demystify this mistery, it would be great! Because I've been visiting many websites and forums (even here) and I can not find a consistent answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% I understand your question. Whether login is a use case or not will depend on what kind of system is being designed.

Comment: I think there is a general answer for this general question (because everytime I have the same doubt for different systems). It's a simple system where the user can create a profile but to edit or to request a service, the user must be logged in. It's a Cloud Application for HR... @whatsisname

Comment: Login is a common use case in a Use Case diagram, which is what your picture is.  See http://yuml.me/diagram/usecase/samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is valid to have a Login use-case.

Having a separate Login use-case is especially useful if the login action is something that the user can do as a stand-alone action (for example, I can login to SO and then decide to view my profile or to post a question or do something else).

What you can't really do is show in a use-case diagram, like the one you have, that the Login use-case is a precondition for the View Profile use-case. This dependency is best expressed in the textual description of each use-case.

Comment: *What you can't really do is show in a use-case diagram, like the one you have, that the Login use-case is a precondition for the View Profile use-case* How about an include relation from `View Profile` to `Login`? Makes sense IMO, because the user has to have done the `Login` use-case before doing the `View Profile` use-case.

Comment: @PeppeL-G, an _include_ relation indicates that you must perform a `Login` every time you do the `View Profile` use case, even if you have just done a `Login` for another reason.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I assume you are right since you probably know UML use-cases better than me, but does `Login` have to be a pre-condition? I've been taught that a use-case should describe everything the user needs to do **from coming to the system** (i.e. starts a fresh session) **until the goal is achieved**, and from this point of view using an *include* relation is equally valid as using it as a pre-condition. Your reasoning is built on that a user do each use-case with a session from before. Does it have to be read like that?